# Ajax Calls getting Mixed Up

Tags: jquery

My Two Ajax calls are getting mixed up

Once the current ajax call is done i want to call **fetchExistingVendors** which is an another Ajax call

I tried to solve it using Jquery's  when ,but still they are getting mixed up

```
 if (confirm("Add this vendor to your current location?") == true)
{
    var async1 =  $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/OrderSnacks/oms/savenewrestaurant?cust_id='+cust_id,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        success: function(response) {
            var resp = response;
            if(resp==true)
            {
                displayingRestaurantsForLabel(temp_location , cust_id);

            }
            else
            {
                alert('Error Inserting Please Try Again');
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('Error inside Fill form request');
        }
    });
    $.when(async1).done(function() {
        fetchExistingVendors(cust_id);
    });
}

 This is second Ajax call


function fetchExistingVendors(cust_id)
{
    //  debugger;
    exisitngvendors = [];
    var url = "http:localhost:8080"
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url+'/OrderSnacks/oms/fetchexistingvendors?cust_id=' + cust_id,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        success: function (responsesss) {
            // showExistingRestaurantAreas(response);
            console.log('hiiiiiiiii'+JSON.stringify(responsesss));
            if(responsesss.length&gt;0)
            {
                alert('length is');
                for(var i=0;i&lt;responsesss.length;i++)
                {
                    if(responsesss[i].vendor_id==='undefined')
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        exisitngvendors.push(responsesss[i].vendor_id);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('Into error ');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should call `fetchExistingVendors()` in the `success` function of the first ajax call.

Comment: You mean i need not use when ??

Comment: The `when` method should work. What does "getting mixed up" mean?

Comment: The `when` method doesn't work because you're not passing the jQuery ajax method to it. You're passing the result of the method, which is the jqXHR Object. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: Could you please let me know how to solve this in this case ??

Answer (score 0):

$.when(async1) will run when async1 is initialized (before the response).

I'm guessing you want to call second ajax only if first one is a success. call the function in the success method:

```
success: function(response) {
        var resp = response;
        if(resp==true){
            displayingRestaurantsForLabel(temp_location , cust_id);
            fetchExistingVendors(cust_id);
        }
        else{
            alert('Error Inserting Please Try Again');
        }
```

edit: can you clarify what do you mean by "they mix up"? what error do you get? what is the response you get?

Comment: Initially i tried this way only ,but response is getting mixed up.